# Does bicep cache the contents of a parameter file ? getting the error The vault name 'kv_xx_dev_xxx_001' is invalid despite changing the name

Tags: azure, azure-bicep

Currently deploying a bicep template file with the parameters stored within a json file, now at first its complaining about the name of my key vault which in this case is `kv_xx_dev_xxx_001`,I can see what I am doing wrong the `_` but I have since changed this to `-`. What I find is that its still making reference to my old parameter despite the fact that i have since changed it on the json file to `kv-xx-dev-xxx-001`.

This is how my deployment is being called.

```
$deployment_name = "Dev-Deploy-$((Get-Date).ToString("ddMMyyyy-HHmmss"))"
az deployment group create --resource-group $resourcegroupName --template-file $TemplateFile --parameters $ParameterFile --name $deployment_name
```

I am running the deployment immediately after fixing on visual studio code.

Answer (score 0):

***Need to check below:***

- As you mentioned you already changed the updated parameter value in `Json` parameter file, verify twice that the changes have been saved properly.
- Use [`az cache purge`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/cache?view=azure-cli-latest#az-cache-purge) as it clears the entire `CLI` object cache in VsCode PowerShell console and then start a new deployment again with the `az deployment group create` command.

[image]

- If still the issue persists, delete the previous [az deployment group delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/deployment/group?view=azure-cli-latest#az-deployment-group-delete) deployment and restart your VScode, then start a new deployment once the changes are updated properly.
- Use [`cat`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.2?topic=c-cat-command#cat__title__4) command to store the parameter file in a variable as cat command helps to read each parameter in sequence and provides a refined output to the `az deployment group create --template-file xxxx --parameters $parameterfile`.

```
$parameters=cat $parameterfile
$parameters
az deployment group create --template-file xxxx --parameters $parameters
```

[image]